# How to create a stripe invoice without customer id

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to generate an invoice through stripe but the API requires a Client ID which I have no idea how to retrieve.

I'm using Session checkout:

method called by ajax

```php
$checkout_session = Checkout\Session::create([
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'line_items' => [[
                'price_data' => [
                    'currency' => 'usd',
                    'unit_amount' => 2000,
                    'product_data' => [
                        'name' => 'Stubborn Attachments',
                        'images' => ["https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png"],
                    ],
                ],
                'quantity' => 1,
            ]],
            'customer_email' => $email,
            'mode' => 'payment',
            'success_url' => $domain. '/success/{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            'cancel_url' => $domain. '/cancel/{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        ]);
```

I receive

```php
[
    "id" => "cs_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    "object" => "checkout.session"
    "allow_promotion_codes" => null
    "amount_subtotal" => 2000
    "amount_total" => 2000
    "billing_address_collection" => null
    "cancel_url" => "http://localhost/cancel/{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}"
    "client_reference_id" => null
    "currency" => "usd"
    "customer" => null
    "customer_details" => null
    "customer_email" => "xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"
    "livemode" => false
    "locale" => null
    "metadata" => []
    "mode" => "payment"
    "payment_intent" => "pi_xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    "payment_method_options" => []
    "payment_method_types" => array:1 [
      0 => "card"
    ]
    "payment_status" => "unpaid"
    "setup_intent" => null
    "shipping" => null
    "shipping_address_collection" => null
    "submit_type" => null
    "subscription" => null
    "success_url" => "http://localhost/success/{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}"
    "total_details" => array:3 [
      "amount_discount" => 0
      "amount_shipping" => 0
      "amount_tax" => 0
    ]
  ]
```

[Create invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/create) requires a customer id which I don't have and have no idea where to get since session checkout creates a customer without giving me an id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Checkout Session in `payment` mode will generate a Payment Intent, not an Invoice. If you want to work solely with Invoices, you Checkout Session is not the right solution. If you don't care about Invoices and just want to be able to charge a customer for a one-off payment then you can continue using Checkout.

If you do want to work solely with Invoices, you need to do the following:

1. Create a [Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create)
2. Pass in the Customer ID when you create as many [Invoice Items](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoiceitems/create) as you need
3. Pass in the Customer ID when you create an [Invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/create) - this will automatically pull in any pending Invoice Items tied to the customer.

This is all summarized in this guide: https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/integration

Comment: thanks for the answer. I mainly use the checkout session because it's a lot less work and I don't have to worry about 3d secure or anything like that. But if I have to use another method, I guess I have no other choice than do the work.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use Invoices? What specific feature of Invoices do you need that Payment Intents doesn't offer?

Comment: It's used to sell services for companies and for that invoices are important. I will see if it's not easier to generate invoices myself and send them through smtp.

Answer (score 0):

"client_reference_id": id in DB 
no more than 100 items in "line_items"
========exemple ============

```
{
    "line_items": [
    {
        "price_data":
        {
            "currency": "usd",
            "product_data":
            {
                "name": "product_name",
                "description": "description",
                "metadata":
                {
                    "id": 29468
                }
            },
            "unit_amount": 11800
        },
        "quantity": 1
    }],
    "mode": "payment",
    "success_url": "https://success_url.com",
    "client_reference_id": 11,
    "customer_email": "email@gmail.com"
}
```

Comment: What does your "no more than 100 items" means ? It's unclear why you said that here